# Javascript: Passing parameters to a method called by callback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, callback

So I've got a save button on my form, which has a callback function that goes off and checks that the user is still authenticated before attempting to save the form, this callback then calls the actual save method that validates the form and saves it if we're authenticated or pops up the login box if we're not. My problem is this save method needs to take in the result of the callback (which is either true or false) and some extra arguments to be validated.

```
function saveButton_Click(sender, eventArgs, var1, var2, var3)
{
    var authenticated = myCallbackFunction(performSave);
}

function performSave(authenticated, var1, var2, var3)
{
    if (authenticated)
    {
        //do some validation and save
    }
    else
    {
        showLoginWindow();
    }
}
```

This is the code I've got so far, which successfully goes off and does the callback and passes the result into performSave, but obviously it's not passing my extra variables in so all my validation stuff is failing. I've tried the following:

```
var authenticated = myCallbackFunction(performSave(authenticated, var1, var2, var3));
```

but this just appears to cause the callback to be skipped and authenticated, var1, var2 etc are always coming through as undefined. So, how can I successfully pass my variables to the performSave method along with the result of my callback?

Comment: Why don't you call `myCallbackFunction` and THEN call `performSave` from `saveButton_Click` function?

Comment: @n0rd authenticated just keeps coming back as undefined doing that

Comment: fix your `myCallbackFunction` then, so it does not return undefined. Anyway you will certainly not be able to pass function return value into that function no matter what you do. Or describe in detail what does what and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a local function scope.

```
function saveButton_Click(sender, eventArgs, var1, var2, var3)
{
    myCallbackFunction(function(authenticated){
        performSave(authenticated, var1, var2, var3);
    });
}
```

Comment: Excellent, this seems to be exactly what I need, thanks very much

Answer (score -1):

Try to separate declaration and assignment, like this:

```
var authenticated = null;
authenticated = myCallbackFunction(performSave(authenticated, var1, var2, var3));
```

Comment: Hmm, tried that, I put a breakpoint on authenticated = null and stepped through. When I tried to step into myCallbackFunction it just skipped straight into performSave with authenticated = null